# Can't use connect-redis in Express.js

Tags: node.js, session, express, redis, cookie-session

I'm studying Express.js and learned how to handle sessions using cookie-session module. I'm trying to use express-session but I have problems.

Previously, I was using cookie-session instead of express-session, and memoryStore worked perfectly. However, I couldn't use connect-redis with cookie-session, for that reason I installed express-session, however with it, I can't use any sort of store, nor memoryStore neither Redis.

The Redis DB is on redistogo and its URI looks like this: (masked for security although this is only to practice)
redis://redistogo:e34d3***********************f4bb@albacore.redistogo.com:10072/

However, when I run "node app", it prints an error.

**My package.json:**

```
{
   "name": "application-name",
   "version": "0.0.1",
   "author": "Me <me@gmail.com>",
   "license": "MIT",
   "private": true,
   "scripts": {
      "start": "node app"
   },
   "dependencies": {
     "express": "4.x.x",
     "cookie-parser": "1.x.x",
     "express-session": "1.x.x",
     "connect-redis": "2.x.x"
   }
}
```

**The "npm ls" show the following:**

```
├─┬ connect-redis@2.0.0
│ ├── debug@0.8.0
│ └── redis@0.10.1
├─┬ cookie-parser@1.0.1
│ ├── cookie@0.1.0
│ └── cookie-signature@1.0.3
├─┬ express@4.0.0
│ ├─┬ accepts@1.0.0
│ │ ├── mime@1.2.11
│ │ └── negotiator@0.3.0
│ ├── buffer-crc32@0.2.1
│ ├── cookie@0.1.0
│ ├── cookie-signature@1.0.3
│ ├── debug@0.8.0
│ ├── escape-html@1.0.1
│ ├── fresh@0.2.2
│ ├── merge-descriptors@0.0.2
│ ├── methods@0.1.0
│ ├── parseurl@1.0.1
│ ├── path-to-regexp@0.1.2
│ ├── qs@0.6.6
│ ├── range-parser@1.0.0
│ ├─┬ send@0.2.0
│ │ └── mime@1.2.11
│ ├─┬ serve-static@1.0.1
│ │ └─┬ send@0.1.4
│ │   ├── fresh@0.2.0
│ │   ├── mime@1.2.11
│ │   └── range-parser@0.0.4
│ ├─┬ type-is@1.0.0
│ │ └── mime@1.2.11
│ └── utils-merge@1.0.0
└─┬ express-session@1.0.3
  ├── buffer-crc32@0.2.1
  ├── cookie@0.1.2
  ├── cookie-signature@1.0.3
  ├── debug@0.7.4
  ├── uid2@0.0.3
  └── utils-merge@1.0.0
```

**My app.js:**

```
//create express app
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

//add express-session
var session = require('express-session');
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(express);
app.use(session({
   store: new RedisStore({
      host: "redis://redistogo:e34d3***********************f4bb@albacore.redistogo.com:10072/"
   })
}));

//routing
var router1 = require('./router/router1')(app);
var router2 = require('./router/router2')(app);

//Deploying server
http.createServer(app).listen(3000, function () {
   console.log('Deployed!!');
});
```

**The error showed when "node app" is ran:**

```
luis@luis-laptop ~/www/express2 $ node app

/home/luis/www/express2/node_modules/connect-redis/lib/connect-redis.js:96
  RedisStore.prototype.__proto__ = Store.prototype;
                                    ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at module.exports (/home/luis/www/express2/node_modules/connect-redis/lib/connect-redis.js:96:41)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/luis/www/express2/app.js:18:42)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

**What session module should I use? And how can I set up it with Redis?**

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(express);
```

should be:

```
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
```

EDIT: You also need to `npm install cookie-parser` and include `var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');` at the top and then `app.use(cookieParser());` right before your `app.use(session({ ... }));`

Comment: The prototype error doesn't show anymore. Now, it shows other when I try to call a route localhost:3000/name

My ./router/router1:
`module.exports = function (app) { app.get('/name', function (req, res) { req.session.name = "Luis"; }); };`

Comment: The new error:
`TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined
    at Object.handle (/home/luis/www/express2/router/router2.js:3:26)
    at next_layer (/home/luis/www/express2/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:103:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/luis/www/express2/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:107:5)
    at c (/home/luis/www/express2/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:195:24)
    at Function.proto.process_params (/home/luis/www/express2/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:251:12)`

Comment: Oh, you also need to `npm install cookie-parser` and include `var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');` at the top and then `app.use(cookieParser());` right before your `app.use(session({ ... }));`

Comment: ok, cookie-parser@1.0.1 installed. I used it before, just to create cookies, and it works perfectly.

Added:
`var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'); app.use(cookieParser());`

after `var app=express();` and before `var expressSession = require('express-session');`

But, it prints the same error. If I use only express-session without Redis, I get the same error `Cannot set property 'name' of undefined     at Object.handle...`

Answer (score 0):

you need redis client

```
var redis = require('redis').createClient();
```